# How to update an individual subfield for on a composite column on PostgreSQL using jOOQ?

Tags: postgresql, jooq, composite-key

On [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.8) there's an example about how to update a subfield of a composite type:

> We can update an individual subfield of a composite column:
>
> `UPDATE mytab SET complex_col.r = (complex_col).r + 1 WHERE ...;`

Assuming we are using jOOQ and code generation, how would that translate to jOOQ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.15, there's no API to allow for accessing members of UDTs yet: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/228

As always, you can easily work around this missing functionality by using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

```java
Field<Integer> r = field("({0}).{1}", COMPLEX_TYPE.R.getDataType(), 
    MYTAB.COMPLEX_COL.getUnqualifiedName(), 
    COMPLEX_TYPE.R.getUnqualifiedName()
);

ctx.update(MYTAB)
   .set(r, r.plus(1))
   .where(...)
   .execute();
```